# PHP - increment date

Tags: php

I have a problem that i really can't solve :

I want to increment a date , let's say today : `$today = date("Y-m-d")`, by 3 months during 3 years.

Example : `2014-09-16` -> incremented by 3 months becomes `2014-12-16` -> incremented by 3 months          becomes `2015-02-16` and so on until my date it's smaller or equal with 3 years from that date , in our example `2017-09-16`.

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried? Methods for incrementing dates in PHP are all over the Internet.

Comment: I know how to increment , it's easy you're right but i want to do it until my date it's equal or smaller than 3 years from first date.

Comment: As the answers state below you would use strtotime until you had incremented upto 3 years.

Comment: You can with if else . Did you tried?

Comment: Please don't dump code in the comments @AndreiKap, edit your original post and add the code there.

Comment: In plain English: if(date +3 months == today + 3 years) { date + 3 months } else { stop } obviously this wouldn't work as it doesn't consider other variables but that is the principle.

Comment: I understand i will try like this , thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is easier when `DatePeriod` is used. It will increment the dates until it reaches the end date.

Example:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2014-09-16'); // set the starting date
$end = new DateTime('2017-09-16'); // set the ending date
$interval = new DateInterval('P3M'); // 3 months interval
$range = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end); // set the period
foreach($range as $date) {
    // so foreach three months, this will loop until the end date
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . '<br/>'; 
}
```

The output will be:

```
2014-09-16
2014-12-16
2015-03-16
2015-06-16
2015-09-16
2015-12-16
2016-03-16
2016-06-16
2016-09-16
2016-12-16
2017-03-16
2017-06-16
```

Comment: Why does `DatePeriod` seem to work properly but not `Date::add()` (see [example #3: Beware when adding months](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php))?

Comment: @kingkero yes an odd behavior indeed, first addition is correct, the second addition doubled

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows

```
while (strtotime($date) < strtotime($end)) { 
$date = strtotime("+2 months", strtotime($date));
 }
```

Read this in detail: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DateTime class:

```
$today = new DateTime('2014-09-16');
$formatted = $today->modify("+3 months");
echo $formatted->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
<?php
$startDate = date("Y-m-d");
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 years", strtotime($startDate )));
echo $startDate."<br/>";
while(strtotime($startDate) < strtotime($endDate) ){
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months", strtotime($startDate )));
    echo $startDate."<br/>";
} 



?>
```